# How to set numeric format when using a query in Excel

Tags: sql, excel, format, numeric, number-formatting

I created a query in Excel which imports the numeric values from several tables and join them together in a Pivot table:

```
SELECT `'Budget 2017$'`.`PROPOSTA BUDGET 2017` 
FROM `S:\30000\ESA_2017.xlsx`.`'Budget 2017$'` `'Budget 2017$'`

UNION ALL

SELECT `'Budget 2017$'`.`PROPOSTA BUDGET 2017` 
FROM `S:\30000\SMM_2017.xlsx`.`'Budget 2017$'` `'Budget 2017$'`
```

The outputs values in the query are in numeric format for the first file (ESA_2017.xlsx), while they are converted in text format for the second file (SMM_2017.xlsx), and I do not understand why. The input values are both in numeric format in the original tables, but the output values in the table created by the query are sometimes numeric sometimes text format.

1. Do you have any clue about the reason why it works differently?
2. How can I change the format output in the query? Is there any code or function which I can include in the query?

Thanks a lot, Stefy

Here the screen of my query code:

[image: Query Code]

Here the screen of my output values:

[image: Output values]